# Angular ng-class doesn't add dynamic class to element

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm having trouble grasping that when `item.dynamicClass = 'article'` why

```
<div class="type" ng-class="{{ item.dynamicClass }}">
```

doesn't return a div like:

```
<div class="type article">
```

but instead returns:

```
<div class="type" ng-class="article">
```

The only way I've been able to get this work is by doing

```
<div class="type" ng-class="itemClass(item.dynamicClass)">

// Controller
$scope.itemClass = function(type) {
  return type;
};
```

I would like a solution which doesn't involve the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the binding braces.  What is passed to [`ng-class`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) is an expression that evaluates to a result, not something to bind ([*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/JgXZ3/)):

```
<div class="type" ng-class="item.dynamicClass">
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried that but I guess not. Also doing class="type {{ item.dynamicClass }}" didn't feel right either.